# Issue with AngularJS processing ASP.NET PartialView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have an issue where HTML obtained from a PartialView Ajax call isn't getting processed by AngularJS.  The problem I have however, is that some JS is setting the element.html property after page load occurred.  I can't really touch this JS as it's filled with more business rules than I know.  Here is what appears to be going on.

MainPage - Has access to Angular scope

```
<dd class="log"></dd>
```

somefile.js - Not in Angular scope (but I can get the MainPage scope via JS if needed)

```
getDataTemplate('.log', 'testid');
function getDataTemplate(placeholder, id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Get/Data' + id,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var placeHolder = $(placeholder);
            placeHolder.html(data);
        }
    });
};
```

The data returned from the "Get/Data" can be anything with Angular, say

```
<div>{{1+2}}</div>
```

Not sure where to go.  I tried a few things, but nothing is working.  Ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: why aren't you using `$http`? you really should look into using `$compile`

Comment: You can create multiple ng app. Each ng-app has its own $rootScope from which you can call broadcast (= publish). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846210/angular-bootstrap-to-run-multiple-angular-apps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs

Comment: @roland - thanks man, that was what I needed.  Move over to an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple `ng-app`.

Each `ng-app` has its own `$rootScope` from which you can call `broadcast` (`publish`).

See those additional, relevant links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846210/angular-bootstrap-to-run-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs